# Performance monitoring script in linux

Tags: linux, performance, scripting

I'm trying to create a script that will allow me to monitor CPU Utilization, Memory Utilization, I/O Utilization, and Network Utilization. Currently, I have a script that should run the necessary commands on linux. Hopefully in the end, I'll be able to run this every 15 or so minutes and then use specific information to analyze the data.  Below is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
########################################################
OUTPUT="ServerPerf`date '+%d%m%y'`.out"
(
echo "=================================================="
echo " Script Starting Time : `date` "
echo "================================================="
echo " Disk I/O Status "
echo "================================================="
echo
iostat
echo
echo "================================================="

echo "##################################################"
echo " NETWORK TCP PARAMETERS STATUS "
echo "##################################################"
echo
echo
netstat -sp tcp
echo
echo " Processes List "
echo
ps -elf
echo
echo " END "
echo
echo "##################################################"
echo "##################################################"
echo " NETWORK CONNECTION PARAMETER "
echo "##################################################"
echo
echo
netstat -an
echo
echo
echo "##################################################"
echo " NETWORK TRAFFIC STATUS ON INTERFACES "
echo "##################################################"
echo
echo
netstat -i
echo
echo
echo "##################################################"
echo " SERVER MEMORY/CPU Utilization Report "
echo "##################################################"
echo
top -d1 -n 5
echo "=================================================="
echo " VMSTAT INFO "
echo "=================================================="
echo
vmstat 5 5
echo
echo "=================================================="
echo " Script Ending Time : `date` "
echo
echo "=================================================="
) >> $OUTPUT
```

Now, I'd like to take useful data from these files that are created. There are a few categories that the data can be sorted into:

1. Load Average
2. CPU Idle Percentage
3. Kernel Utilization
4. Memory Utilization
5. Swapping activity

I'm trying to use these commands to generate these 5 files and seem to be having difficulty.

```
grep "load avg" /home/test/logs/ServerPerf180610.out | awk '{ print $6 }' | awk -F, '{ print $1 }' > load_avg.txt
grep "CPU states" /home/test/logs/ServerPerf180610.out | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk -F% '{ print $1 }' > cpu_idle.txt
grep "CPU states" /home/test/logs/ServerPerf180610.out | awk '{ print $7 }' | awk -F% '{ print $1 }' > cpu_kernel.txt
grep "Memory" /home/test/logs/ServerPerf180610.out | awk '{ print $5 }' | awk -FG '{ print $1 }' > memory_util.txt
grep "Memory" /home/test/logs/ServerPerf180610.out | awk '{ print $11 }' | awk -FG '{ print $1 }' > swap_util.txt
```

While these commands run the output files are just empty. Does anyone know why I'm unable to generate these files?

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you,
Aaron

**UDPATE**: Here is a copy of the output file:
http://www.queencitytech.com/ServerPerfRepo180610.out

Comment: I can't tell for sure because I have a different version.  But have you tried just removing the awk portions for troubleshooting?  That is, use "grep... > load_avg.txt" instead of the intervening two awk commands?

Comment: the top command is being used in this script. i've tried removing awk but but doesn't want to output anything either

Comment: Is there anything in the /home/test/logs/ServerPerf... file?

Comment: I can't help with the problem at hand, but are you aware of Cacti? http://www.cacti.net (possibly not what you need but to have dropped the name.)

Comment: And does the command ever finish?  The **top** command alone should take at least 5 seconds.

Comment: I've added a link to the original post so that you can see the ServerPerf...file and its contents.

Comment: Yes, the top command does complete. You can see this from the output file.

Comment: Sorry -- I didn't see the file earlier when I responded.

Comment: Oh, it's okay. I just added it after you mentioned it :)

Comment: You should consider using using the sysstat package as it includes `sar` to collect performance data over time and report on it. This includes much of the same performance data you’re looking for.  https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is a typo, but the files you are searching and the files you are creating are different.

That is, the `OUTPUT=...` line says **DAY-MONTH-YEAR**, but the grep lines say **MONTH-DAY-YEAR**

**EDIT**:  OK, you posted the output file.  There are all kinds of special chars in there, from the `top` command.  Can you add the batch (`top -d1 -n1 -b`) arg to `top` to hide that?

**ANOTHER EDIT**: Your grep commands appear to be case-specific.  Is that intentional?  The result has no matches for several of your grep filters.  Try adding ignore case (grep -i) to the commands.  Also, you are searching for "load avg" but the output says "load average" so you should never find it.

Comment: Actually, I apologize that was a typo on my part. When I ran the command it followed the same as the files.

Comment: that makes sense. when i add the ignore case and proper "load average" search all i'm getting in the file is "day" with 4 zeros underneath?

Comment: Did you also add the batch option to top?  I think that top is generating screen control codes to highlight, blink, home, etc, and that might be messing up your output.

Comment: Also, there is no "memory" data.  There are sections called Memory, but if you return only those lines you get no data.  Also, there are no lines called "CPU States".  Where did you get your filters?  They just don't exist in the data.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about the batch option. I actually have found this on a blog and have been trying to make it work for awhile now. Here is the page (part 2) http://kumudunix.blogspot.com/2010/01/unix-performance-monitoring-data_08.html It was originally written for Solaris and I modified some commands so they would work on linux. I guess its possible that by changing them I broke the script.

Comment: From that blog, you can get to Part 1 which has the original script. However I did find some errors such as a missing "|" before each of the awk's. I do see what you mean by "memory" data.

Comment: Well, I think you can make it work, but I also think that you are better off re-starting.  There are probably linux commands and utilities that give you what you want.  If, however, the point is to grow your own in an effort to learn, I say keep at it.  But check your inputs and the steps, rather than waiting til the end.